# "Repair" listing environment when used in the enumerate environment

Tags: listings, enumerate, tcblisting, tcbinputlisting

In the code given below, the my listing environment gets skewed while in the `enumerate` environment:

[image]

How to fix the code so that the listing box inside the `enumerate` environment, looks like that out side of the `enumerate` environment?  Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
numbersep=22pt,
frame=none
}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\current@boxwidth}
\newtcolorbox{titlebox}[1][]{enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  left skip=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  boxsep=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  size=minimal,
  #1
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    colbacktitle={blue},
    code={\setlength{\current@boxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}\colorlet{outercolbacktitle}{tcbcol@backtitle}},% Calculate the box width
    title={\begin{titlebox}[width=\current@boxwidth,colupper=tcbcol@title,colback=outercolbacktitle]#2\end{titlebox}},
    #1,
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is how the \texttt{mylisting} box appears outside of the \texttt{enumerate} environment:

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,right = 2cm]{\bfseries{``cubemaster'' Usage}}
cubemaster(13);
\end{mylisting}

This is how the \texttt{mylisting} box appears inside of the \texttt{enumerate} environment:

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item 
\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,right = 2cm]{\bfseries{``cubemaster'' Usage}}
cubemaster(13);
\end{mylisting}

\item This is just some random text

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The cause of this is basically to due to the `hbox` option

Comment: As @ChristianHupfer sugested, try removing the `hbox` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works with an additional minipage

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
numbersep=22pt,
frame=none
}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\current@boxwidth}
\newtcolorbox{titlebox}[1][]{enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  left skip=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  boxsep=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  size=minimal,
  #1
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    colbacktitle={blue},
    code={\setlength{\current@boxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}\colorlet{outercolbacktitle}{tcbcol@backtitle}},% Calculate the box width
    title={\begin{titlebox}[width=\current@boxwidth,colupper=tcbcol@title,colback=outercolbacktitle]#2\end{titlebox}},
    #1,
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is how the \texttt{mylisting} box appears outside of the \texttt{enumerate} environment:

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,right = 2cm]{\bfseries{``cubemaster'' Usage}}
cubemaster(13);
\end{mylisting}

This is how the \texttt{mylisting} box appears inside of the \texttt{enumerate} environment:

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,right = 2cm]{\bfseries{``cubemaster'' Usage}}
cubemaster(13);
\end{mylisting}
\end{minipage}
\item This is just some random text

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternative is to do `\item\mbox{}\par` and add suitable ad ho negative vspace. The `-\baselineskip` is also ad hoc in your answer. in both cases manual adjustment is needed if not digging into tcolorbox code I guess. (I tried ``\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\ht\strutbox}`` which seems to give about same result as yours).

Comment: @jfbu \mbox{} doesn't work for me. The line number (the gray 1) then wanders into the tcolorbox.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I did not notice :-( If you don't mind I will suppress my comment after a while.

Comment: @jfbu Imho it is useful to see also what doesn't work, so leave the comment.

Comment: hmm.. maybe you can add that tidbit to your answer? (without mentioning me, I am too modest to wish credit for my errors...)